# Hide tooltip of truncated checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a checkbox which is resized together with my main form. The text of this checkbox has some relevant information, so it got an own tooltip control (with mutliline content).

If the form gets small enough the text of my checkbox is truncated (AutoEllipsis = true). But if i move my mouse over this control i get two tooltips which overlap each other. The first shows the complete text of the truncated checkbpox and the second shows the tooltip i added in the code.

I presume that the first tooltip is caused by setting the AutoEllipsis property to true?
What can i do to prevent this builtin tooltip to be shown? I didn't find any properties i could overload or something...
If possible I would like to keep the AutoEllipsis property as it handles the truncation of too large text.

Comment: See Vladimir's answer at the bottom over [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c05740de-a71a-4952-ac52-b72e9f323204/cannot-disable-a-tooltip-for-a-label) in the MSDN forums for one possible approach.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link. Regrettably this doesn't work for me as this refers to labels and not checkboxes. I tried both approaches mentioned there, but it seems that checkboxes don't have the "showToolTip" field.

Answer (score 1):

**With Windows.Controls :** You can maybe override the method [OnToolTipOpening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.ontooltipopening.aspx)
to cancel the first tooltip

**With Windows.Forms :** You can override the method WndProc and treat the [TTM_POPUP message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The question was tagged as WinForms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wasn't able to find out which value I have to define for TTM_POPUP. Even monitoring the messages of the checkbox with Spy++ didn't show something useful. I checked all TTM_ messages but they aren't listed in Spy++. Do you have an idea why?